# PyPy: "ImportError: No module named xlrd"

Tags: python-2.7, xlrd, pypy

I am using PyPy 2.2.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I want to use the `xlrd` module for my program but running the programming with pypy throws me an import error. How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you download it?

Comment: yes I did install it and it works fine with Python

Comment: Maybe the location of the modules are different for python and PyPy?

Answer (score 5):

`PyPy` has its own `site-packages` path that should be (and by default is) different from that of your `CPython` installation's `site-packages`. And just like it applies for `CPython` for easy package installation, your best bet is to install `pip` for your `PyPy` version.

The quickest way to begin the `pip` installation process (if you don't already have it installed) is to check that you have the module `ensurepip` installed. This is done by opening a command line instance, starting the `PyPy` `REPL` (the command `pypy` should do) and checking for yourself with `import ensurepip`. If the module imports safely, then you are in luck and should be able to move forward with setting up `pip` for `PyPy`. With the `REPL` still open and `ensurepip` imported, run the following:

```
ensurepip.bootstrap(upgrade=True)
```

The line above should install `pip` for your `PyPy` installation. Next, you should exit the `REPL` and change your current directory to the `bin` folder of your `PyPy` installation. For ubuntu, this is usually located at `/usr/lib/pypy/bin`. Depending on your version of `PyPy` that path may be slightly different: instead of `/usr/lib/pypy/bin` you may have something like `/usr/lib/pypy2.2.1/bin` or `/usr/lib/pypy221/bin`. Just make sure you are aware of that. In summary, the following, when run in your command line, should take care of the `xlrd` installation for you:

```
cd /usr/lib/pypy/bin
sudo ./pip install xlrd
```

or you can just do (still in the command line):

```
pypy -m pip install xlrd
```

If ***either*** of the above ran smoothly, you should be left with `xlrd` installed for your `PyPy`. You can double check by opening a `PyPy` `REPL` and trying to import `xlrd`.

Of course, if your `PyPy` did not come with the `ensurepip` module installed, it may not be too fun trying to get `pip` setup. But as mentioned above, having `ensurepip` installed may go a long way to helping you set up `pip` and as a result install any package you wish to see installed for `PyPy`.

Still, if your `PyPy` installation did not come with `ensurepip`, then the following, when run from the command line, should help set up `pip` and then install `xlrd`:

1. First `cd` to your `Downloads`

`cd ~/Downloads`

2. Download the get-pip.py script using `wget`

`wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`

3. Run the script with `pypy` under `sudo`

`sudo pypy get-pip.py`

4. Then install `xlrd`

`sudo pypy -m install xlrd`

I hope this proves useful.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to install a new pip for PyPy as it has a different space for storing modules.